# Need help troubleshooting Teensy 3.6 SPI to DAC8568

Tags: noise, spi, embedded, troubleshooting, teensy

running out of things to check with this problem I'm having.

I designed a board around the Teensy 3.6 microprocessor, and I wanted to connect a DAC8568 chip to it for some analog outputs.  It works over SPI, and I have verified that it does "work".

**HOWEVER** it only works when I have an oscilloscope probe on the SCK line!

[image: Schematic 1]
[image: Schematic 2]

Here are two images to my schematic.  I am using SPI1 interface, as SPI0 is being used for communication with a CANFD controller.  I have verified that I get a clock output, I get a chip select, and data "flows".

[image: Board Layout 1]
[image: Board Layout 2]

Here is two pictures of my PCB layout.  The second image shows the two lines.  The top one being the SCK1 net, and the bottom being the MOSI1 net.

Like I said, the device seems to only work when I put an oscilloscope probe on SCK1 (on powerup), and if I take it off, it continues to work.  The probe is 8pF, 10MOhm.

[CODE](https://pastebin.com/mK4r0DfY)

NOTES: 9.2.1 says MSB first
7.3 shows that I should be getting data on the falling clock edge.
For this reason I chose SPI Mode 1 (CPOL 0, CPHA 1).
Just for kicks I tried with all the other SPI modes (0, 2, 3) and none worked.

Any idea what might be causing this??  I will continue trying to debug, but I would appreciate any help possible!! Thanks :)

Comment: *un-probing, continues to work* suggests an initialization problem. At some (early) time after power-up, the SPI is initialized - perhaps an "extra" clock is seen or missed. Try various delays after power-up.

Comment: Sometimes, adding a tiny capacitance to ground on the clock line will get rid of spurious edges and high-frequency garbage. Try 15pF, likely the same as your scope probe. Not exactly "ideal" but can point you in the right direction for a real solution.